# Cumulative plot for many variables in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there an easy way to do a cumulative plot of many variables with matplotlib/numpy?

I'm thinking of a graph like this http://atlassian.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/jira/cumulative-flow-diagram.png.

For example I have data `a=[0,3,6]`, `b=[0,3,4]` and this is supposed to become a count plot
`[(0, a=1, b=1), (3, a=2, b=2), (4, a=2, b=3), (6, a=3, b=3)]`. Therefore no binning, but rather all x-values get a point with the count of a particular variable below this value. The a and b values should be stacked above each other.

I can imagine how to implement a complicating interlacing preprocessing with bisect, but I can't see an easy solution.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Another explanation of the accumulated counting:
I have multiple data rows with x values. E.g. `a=[0,3,6]`, `b=[0,3,4]`, `c=[1, 7]`

I need a graph for each data row. The possible value of x coordinates for the plot is the union of all data row values. Here `[0,1,3,4,6,7]`.

For each of these total x value the y value for a particular row would be how many of the value in that data are below the x coordinate. Therefore for the x coordinates `x=[0,1,3,4,6,7]` I'd get `ya=[1,1,2,2,3,3]`, `yb=[1,1,2,3,3,3]`, `yc=[0,1,1,1,1,2]`.
And of course I will use the stacked plot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of plot you mentioned in the link can be achieved with `stackplot`. See eg this example of the gallery: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/stackplot_demo.html

What you mean with the example data is not all clear to me. Can you give a more elaborate example of the data you have and what you want to obtain?

EDIT: A very simple approach:

```
>>> a=[0,3,6]
>>> b=[0,3,4]
>>> c=[1, 7]
>>> 
>>> x = [0,1,3,4,6,7]
>>> 
>>> ya = []
>>> 
>>> val = 0
>>> for i in x:
...     if i in a:
...         val += 1
...         ya.append(val)
...     else:
...         ya.append(val)
... 
>>> ya
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

But probably there will be more efficient ways. Do you use numpy or pandas to do the analysis? Or with plain lists?

Comment: Looks good :) I've updated the explanation of the accumulated counting for multiple data arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I use numpy, but was going to learn pandas soon anyway. I actually need a small adjustment because sometimes there is more than `+=1` values. And also I need to do that for all variables simultaneously. But it works :) I thought there might be an elegant numpy solution which is more efficient :) It seems like a standard task.

Comment: Maybe you can take al look at ``bincount`` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)